# I can not process the keys in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried to process the keys in my dictionary, but when the function reaches the list, nothing happens, how can I solve this problem? What am I doing wrong?

At the moment my function returns:

```
{
  'KEY1': 1,
  'KEY2': 2,
  'KEY3': {
    'KEY4': {
      'KEY5': [{
        'key6': 3,
        'key7': {
          'key8': 4
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

But my function should return:

```
{
  'KEY1': 1,
  'KEY2': 2,
  'KEY3': {
    'KEY4': {
      'KEY5': [{
        'KEY6': 3,
        'KEY7': {
          'KEY8': 4
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

```
obj = {
  'key1': 1,
  'key2': 2,
  'key3': {
    'key4': {
      'key5': [{
        'key6': 3,
        'key7': {
          'key8': 4
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

def rec_keys(node, case = 'uppercase'):
    output = {}

    for key in node.keys():
        if case == 'lowercase':
            new_key = key.lower()
        elif case == 'uppercase':
            new_key = key.upper()

        if isinstance(node[key], dict):
            output[new_key] = rec_keys(node[key], case)
        else:
            output[new_key] = node[key]

    return output

print(rec_keys(obj))
```

offtop: stackoverflow asks me to add more information, but I have nothing more to add

Comment: @PedroLobito, I'm new in Python, how I can solve this problem? :( Don't understand...

Comment: @PedroLobito, no, keys of list doesn't have upper case

Comment: So let me get this clear, if the key is `lower`, you want it `upper` an vice-versa, is that it?

Comment: @PedroLobito, One of the arguments of the function is the option in which I want to translate all the keys, at the moment I want to translate them from lowercase to upper

Comment: the keys not getting changed are the one inside the `list` on `key5`, you've to loop that list too.

Comment: @PedroLobito, yes, I know, but how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
def change_keys(obj, func="upper"):

    if func == "upper":
         func = lambda x : x.upper()
    elif func == "lower":
        func = lambda x : x.lower()

    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        new = {}
        for k, v in obj.items():
            new[func(k)] = change_keys(v, func)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        new = []
        for v in obj:
            new.append(change_keys(v, func))
    else:
        return obj
    return new

print(change_keys(obj, "upper"))

# {'KEY1': 1, 'KEY2': 2, 'KEY3': {'KEY4': {'KEY5': [{'KEY6': 3, 'KEY7': {'KEY8': 4}}]}}}
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/2d57dc37b4)

Answer (score 0):

maybe try switching the lowercase function with the uppercase to make uppercase be first... idk but from personal experience it somehow works out and actually has a difference.

Comment: if I want to translate from upper case to lower case?